# Scrollable Container inside a Column

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout

I tried a few different approaches but I can't get this to work. The layout I want to achieve is really simple and it's a breeze to implement in native Android:

- Fixed Container on top (blue)
- Scrollable Container below (red). A ListView won't work in my case.

I tried to use `SingleChildScrollView`, but it doesn't seem to work inside a `Column`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or I'm not using the right widgets...

My result:

[image]

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Red container should be scrollable'),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 700.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                child: Text('I will have a column here'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Column` widget does not support scrolling. In order to make it work you may switch to `ListView`, but current implementation lack of some sort of header for sections. In order to get them you may use [sticky_headers](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_headers#-readme-tab-) package like that:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new StickyHeader(
                header: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                content: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Red container should be scrollable'),
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 700.0,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                        child: Text('I will have a column here'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          }));
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you, at least I know I have to find another way of implementing what I need.

Answer (score 194):

I think that maybe after a year you have managed to do that.

But for others searching for the same problem, the easiest way is to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` inside an `Expanded` widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 100.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Red container should be scrollable'),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 700.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                  child: Text('I will have a column here'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Yes! Worked for my.

Comment: I love Flutter but sometimes, I feel like .... I am having so many child-z just to achieve a very simple stuff

Comment: That's brilliant! Should change this answer to be the best one ;D

Comment: This should be the accepted solution

Comment: Can you please explain the reason why it works with Expanded, i couldn't find it in docs

Comment: Because SingleChildScrollView do not have a bounded height it assumes its height based on the children (in this case 700), and overflows the available space, so you need to use the Expanded widget, it will calculate the remaining available height for the column and tell SingleChildScrollView to use it.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: In some cases you can use "Flexible" instead "Expanded"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to implement a working layout using a `Stack`, the only down-side being that if I have a `TextField` and I scroll down, the cursor 'bubble' shows up above my top container... which is kind of ugly. The order of my widgets in the `Stack` doesn't affect this.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biru8.png)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
  Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 700.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                    child: TextField(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expand your column to maximal size, wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` into `Flexible`:

```
return Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    //header
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 50,
      child: const Text("Header"),
    ),
    Flexible(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          //top
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 100,
            child: const Text("Top"),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            height: 5000,
          ),
          //bottom
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 100,
            child: const Text("Bottom"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )),
    //footer
    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50, child: const Text("Footer")),
  ],
);
```